# String not Taking with Special Character

Tags: shell

```
cd /etc/squid/
SQUID=/etc/squid/squid.conf
WORD="acl blockclients src 192.168.5.0/255.255.255.0"
WORD1="acl banned src "/etc/squid/our_512kbps.txt""
WORD2="http_access deny banned"
WORD3="http_reply_access deny banned"
WORD4="http_access allow blockclients"
WORD5="http_reply_access allow all"

sed -i "s/LINE1/&\n$WORD/" $SQUID
sed -i "s/LINE2/&\n$WORD1/" $SQUID
sed -i "s/LINE3/&\n$WORD2/" $SQUID
sed -i "s/LINE4/&\n$WORD3/" $SQUID
sed -i "s/LINE5/&\n$WORD4/" $SQUID
sed -i "s/LINE6/&\n$WORD5/" $SQUID
```

I am new for Shell programming please any one help me

I am getting error on this line

```
WORD="acl blockclients src 192.168.5.0/255.255.255.0"
```

like

```
./internetblock.sh: line 7: blockclients: command not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Note: if you want to include `"` inside a quotation, you need to escape it with backslash. I'm talking about `WORD1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `WORD` contains a `/` which is also the `sed` expression separator. That's why `sed` throws an error. The easiest way to fix this is to use a character that is not present in your text as the `sed` separator e.g. `|`.

Try changing your `sed` commands to use `|` instead of `/`:

```
sed -i "s|LINE1|&\n$WORD|" $SQUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` with parameter expansions is tricky. Given the structure of your problem, iterating over the file may be a better fit:

```
cd /etc/squid/
SQUID=/etc/squid/squid.conf
WORD="acl blockclients src 192.168.5.0/255.255.255.0"
WORD1='acl banned src "/etc/squid/our_512kbps.txt"'   # Use single quotes for embedded double quotes
WORD2="http_access deny banned"
WORD3="http_reply_access deny banned"
WORD4="http_access allow blockclients"
WORD5="http_reply_access allow all"

{
     read LINE1
     printf "%s\n%s\n" "$LINE1" "$WORD"
     read LINE2
     printf "%s\n%s\n" "$LINE2" "$WORD1"
     read LINE3
     printf "%s\n%s\n" "$LINE3" "$WORD2"
     read LINE4
     printf "%s\n%s\n" "$LINE4" "$WORD3"
     read LINE5
     printf "%s\n%s\n" "$LINE5" "$WORD4"
     cat   # Any remaining lines from the input file
} < "$SQUID"
```

If you are using `bash` or another shell that supports arrays, it can be shortened greatly:

```
cd /etc/squid/
SQUID=/etc/squid/squid.conf
WORDS=( "acl blockclients src 192.168.5.0/255.255.255.0"
        'acl banned src "/etc/squid/our_512kbps.txt"'
        "http_access deny banned"
        "http_reply_access deny banned"
        "http_access allow blockclients"
        "http_reply_access allow all" )

{ for word in "${WORDS[@]}"; do
      read LINE;
      printf "%s\n%s\n" "$LINE" "$word"
  done
  cat
} < "$SQUID"
```